# PHP fopen() error in testing

Tags: php, csv, phpunit, fopen

I have the following file structure

> src/functions.php
>
> src/sample.csv
>
> tests/functionsTest.php

In the *functions.php*, I have this function to read a csv file

```
<?php
function readCSV($csvFile){
        $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
            $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        }
        fclose($file_handle);
        return $line_of_text;
    }
?>
```

In the *functionsTest.php* file, I have

```
<?php

require_once('src/functions.php');
use phpunit\framework\TestCase;

class test extends TestCase {

    public function testReadDataFromFile() {
        $filename = "./sample.csv";
        $data = readCSV($filename);
        $this->assertEquals("test data", $data);
    }
}
?>
```

When I run the test code using **>phpunit tests/functionsTest.php**, I get error saying

```
fopen(./sample.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

But if I call the function from the same *src/functions.php*, I get the data

```
 print_r(readCSV("sample.csv"));
```

So I tried to move the *sample.csv* file to the test folder -

> tests/sample.csv

but still I get the same error

I think I am missing something simple.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the single dot `.` represents the current directory. Calling your script from `tests/` and specifying `.` will look for `sample.csv` in your `tests` directory, when it's actually in `src/`.

You want to specify the directory using `$filename = "../src/sample.csv";`

Also note that you may want to use [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) instead, or specify an absolute path to the file (e.g. `/YourName/YourProject/src/sample.csv`), instead of a relative one.

P.S. You can print out those magic constants like `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` when running your script to troubleshoot issues like this.